# Initialing variables some variables from constructor and some from user in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor

I am writing a program and I want to initialize some variables from the constructor and others from the input of user for example

```
class Flower():
    def __init__(self, ftype="rose",noPedals=6,price=12.23):
        self._ftype=ftype
        self._noPedals=noPedals
       self._price=price
   def setFtype(self, ftype):
       self._ftype=ftype
   def setNoPedal(self, noPedals):
       self._noPedals=noPedals

   def setPrice(self, price):
       self._price=price

   def getFtype(self):
       return self._ftype
   def getNoPedal(self):
       return self._noPedals
   def getPrice(self):
       return self._price

if __name__=="__main__":
F1=Flower()
print("The first flower is ",F1.getFtype()," its has ",F1.getNoPedal()," pedals and its price is ",F1.getPrice())
F1.setFtype("Lily")
F1.setNoPedal(4)
F1.setPrice(20)
print("Now the first flower is ",F1.getFtype()," its has ",F1.getNoPedal()," pedals and its price is ",F1.getPrice())
F2=Flower(9,78.9)
print("The second flower is ",F2.getFtype()," its has ",F2.getNoPedal()," pedals and its price is ",F2.getPrice())
```

I am getting the output,
    The first flower is  rose  its has  6  pedals and its price is  12.23
    Now the first flower is  Lily  its has  4  pedals and its price is  20
    The second flower is  9  its has  78.9  pedals and its price is  12.23

I am getting 9 inplace of the name of the flower how do I skip the values I do not want to enter into the constructor of the class

Comment: Since you put flags, just put whichever of these flag you want: `ftype="rose",noPedals=6,price=12.23`. And you will be able to take some out.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by flags if I enter a variable of number it still is considered ftype

Comment: See below. That is what I mean

Comment: and if I enter two variables the first one is considered ftype and the second one is considered noPedals

Comment: Not if you enter it like a flag

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 optional arguments. If you pass them without telling which ones you use (like you did) it is assumed to be from left to right. This means that

```
F2=Flower(9,78.9)
```

is interpreted as

```
F2=Flower(ftype=9,noPedals=78.9)
```

and `price` gets the default value. To solve this explicitly write which argument you mean. In your case it should be the following:

```
F2=Flower(noPedals=9, price=78.9)
```